# Using ''textpos'' in a colored page

Tags: color, textpos

I want to write a text in a given position in a colored page. So I used the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

 %

 \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}  

 \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{10mm}

 \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}

 \textblockorigin{5mm}{5mm} 

 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%

\usepackage[ paperwidth=400mm, paperheight=300mm]{geometry} 

 \usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%

\begin{document}

% 

\pagecolor{yellow}

 \pagestyle{empty}

 \begin{textblock}{10} (20,9)

{\lipsum[1-2]}

 \end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

but the result is only a yellow page without text. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must insert in the options of textpos: `overlay`.